# Accessing or changing WCF port even if the port is busy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, routes, port

I want to interrogate a WCF service and I need a robust solution.
It's not acceptable that the service go down just because there is another program using the same port.

Port are technical details that should be transparent to the end user.

Which solution can I use?

Can I try so look for the service at two endpoint with different port numbers? Or help the conflict even using the same port?

Comment: I do not understand. As you already said, port is a technical detail and should be maintained during service deployment. It is a responsibility of the administrator to avoid conflicts, not the service client or the service itself.

Comment: I think the objective of informatic is to make software take care of problems that can be solved without an human intervent. It should be really simple to negotiate different ports. If the negotiation fails and Admin will be needed, but I would like to try at least 2 or 3 ports. Many software already handle it.

Comment: I think there is a border of software taking care of problems, especially infrastructural ones. Going into that direction, what else your software should do? Change its hard drive location if current drive is running out of space?

Comment: I think it's a bit different.. full HD is similar to an hardware failure. I think trying different port is like logging both on DB and filesystem because I want to help network problems, or using load balancing, replicated architecture, or more.. switching from one port to another is really trivial.. have you ever met a similar problem on Android or Ios? In many scenarios Administrator doesn't exist and it's not trivial to understand wich program is conflicting with mine.. but this is just my humble opinion.

Comment: maybe that's because I was thinking more about enterprise servers where administrators do exists and must do their job.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you need to “abstract” your WCF Service / multiple endpoints from client applications then you may want to consider the WCF [Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The Routing Service is a generic SOAP intermediary that acts as a message router. The RoutingService is implemented as a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service in the System.ServiceModel.Routing namespace. The Routing Service exposes one or more service endpoints that receive messages and then routes each message to one or more client endpoints based on the message content.

In addition to the destination client endpoints associated with each filter definition in the filter table, you can also create a list of **backup endpoints** that the message will be routed to in the event of a transmission failure. If an error occurs and a backup list is defined for the filter entry, the Routing Service will attempt to send the message to the first endpoint defined in the list. If this transmission attempt fails, the service will try the next endpoint, and continue this process until the transmission attempt succeeds, returns a non-transmission related error, or all endpoints in the backup list have returned a transmission error.

Comment: yes, it's what I need. To define backup endpoint. When the server starts it could look for an available port between i.e. 80 and 90. The client is trying to contact the host should know that he can contact on port from 80 to 90. And simply try. I want the software to be fault tolerant. It will be faster than any human intervent. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I thougth the reason is bound to firewalls.. in enterprise level apps the single port should be opened.. so it's better to already know the ports.